# Kernel 4.10/4.12 with AMDGPU-PRO?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, amd-graphics

Is it possible to use AMDGPU-PRO driver with a newer Kernel under Ubuntu 16.04?

I couldn't find much information, sorry if I missed something.

So I converted my friend to linux. Since **Linux Mint 18.2** was released yesterday and it's based on Ubuntu, I installed it for him with **kernel 4.10**.

He got a **XFX Fury**. I tried installing the driver from AMD (**AMDGPU-PRO** for Ununtu 16.04) but after rebooting, I got black screen with an underscore (not blinking). Tried with kernel 4.8, 4.10, 4.12.

Rebooting in recovery mode, I found out there is an error with the display in xorg.log. Trying to boot with **nomodeset** works in **software rendering mode**.

I reinstalled Linux and now everything is running perfectly without this driver, but Overwatch need a videocard installed :P. (Running kern. 4.10)

I personally have an old graphic card (GTX 580) which runs beautifully under **Kernel 4.12**, released yesterday, with both closed-source driver and **nouveau**.

I was wondering why the AMD driver wasn't working. Unfortunatly I don't remember the exact error message - but I'll try to find the same message ont he internet and update this question. In the mean time I though maybe someone had a solution.

Thanks to anyone how may have some tips for us!

Cheers!

Little disappointment addition: I guess Ubuntu people doesn't care since they asked me to post this here instead - for what the linux community is worth :P

Comment: I'm having similar issues. I tried amdgpu-pro on 4.14.0-rc1 and got some broken symbols errors. Also tried kernel 4.12. However, I don't think even the amdgpu open-source driver is active in my setup. Even that may be sufficient.  Isn't `nouveau` for nvidia cards? See my related question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394661/cant-boot-with-kernel-modesetting

Answer (score 0):

I am using a RX470 with the open source AMDGPU driver and kernel 4.10 on Linux Mint 18.4 Mate and I can't see any difference from before when I had 4.8 and AMGDPU-PRO, including Steam games.

Maybe you should try amdgpu. In fact it got installed by default when I installed 18.2, tested with glxgears then installed Steam and it just worked.

Some games did not like the Steam overlay and I had to disable that, but that's what I do anyway.