# Can't boot with Kernel Modesetting

Tags: linux-kernel, video, laptop, amd-graphics, kms

I need to enable [Kernel Modesetting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting) in order for my video card to be used with the amdgpu driver, but I have this new Lenovo IdeaPad laptop that won't boot unless I boot the kernel with the `nomodeset` option. Is there anything I can do to debug KMS support for this hardware? It's a Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15ABR. Kernel version is 4.14.0-rc1.

And here's the VGA device info:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA Compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo [1002:9874] (rev c8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,
I've gotten this laptop booting with kernel-modesetting support, and the amdgpu drivers are now being used.

I followed the steps in Gentoo's wiki: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AMDGPU

I'm not sure which of the following changes were required, or if they were all necessary but what I did was:

- Enable "Build HDMI/DisplayPort HD-audio codec support" in my kernel
- Disable the `ATI Radeon` param in my kernel
- Included all the carrizo firmware files directly into my kernel
- Remove `ati` and `radeon` modules from `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`
- Blacklist the `radeon` module in `/etc/modprobe.d`

For some of these steps, you can see more detail in the gentoo wiki page linked above.

After all that, I removed the options `quiet`, `splash`, and `nomodeset` from my grub kernel params, and my display didn't hang anymore! `Xorg.0.log` confirmed the amdgpu drivers are now being used.